# Есть ли КАРДИНАЛЬНАЯ РАЗНИЦА в функциях ниже (*не учитывая как осуществляется вызов)?

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++, указатели

```
void test(int* arg)
{
    *arg = 1;
}

void test(int& arg)
{
    arg = 2;
}
```

//*не учитывая как осуществляется вызов 1 или 2 способ (результат тот же)

```
int x = 0;
test(&x); // 1
test(x);  // 2
```

Comment: Дополняя ответы ниже - в первой функции сигнатура должна быть `void test(int* const arg)` для _полной идентичности_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обе функции абсолютно идентичные. Код из дизассемблера visual studio.

```
    ;void test(int& arg)
009E16B0  push        ebp  
009E16B1  mov         ebp,esp  
009E16B3  sub         esp,0C0h  
009E16B9  push        ebx  
009E16BA  push        esi  
009E16BB  push        edi  
009E16BC  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]  
009E16C2  mov         ecx,30h  
009E16C7  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
009E16CC  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
    ;arg = 2;
009E16CE  mov         eax,dword ptr [arg]  
009E16D1  mov         dword ptr [eax],2  


    ;void test(int* arg)
009E16F0  push        ebp  
009E16F1  mov         ebp,esp  
009E16F3  sub         esp,0C0h  
009E16F9  push        ebx  
009E16FA  push        esi  
009E16FB  push        edi  
009E16FC  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h]  
009E1702  mov         ecx,30h  
009E1707  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
009E170C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
    ;*arg = 1;
009E170E  mov         eax,dword ptr [arg]  
009E1711  mov         dword ptr [eax],1
```

Answer (score 3):

Вообще говоря - нет, не считая того, что в первую функцию можно передать несуществующий адрес (`nullptr`), а во вторую - только имеющуюся переменную (в широком смысле слова, lvalue).

Answer (score 2):

Конкретно для ваших функций _ как сказал `Harry`, но когда видим  в аргументе указатель, мы не знаем имеем ли мы дело с одним обьектом или с  множеством таких обьектов. Любое арифметическое действие с указателем(если он не нулевой), приведет к тому, что мы будем работать уже с другим обьектом или с неопределенным участком памяти.

С аргументом ссылька, мы знаем, что в функцию передается конкретный обьект. Любое действие над ссылькой будет просто инвариантом обьекта, на который мы ссылались, поэтому безопасность обеспечена.
Имея ввиду все это, всегда, когда имеете дело с конкретным одним обьектом, лучше работать со ссылькой, чем заморачиваться с указателем.

Answer (score 1):

В случае с указателем с точки зрения **клиента** не очевидно, что переменная передается "по ссылке" (в том смысле, что копирования данных типа не происходит, в случае с настоящей C++-ссылкой это не так явно, ибо нет оператора взятия адреса `&`)